# EC2 fails to connect via FTPS, but works locally

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ftp, amazon-ec2, ftplib

I'm running Python 2.6.5 on ec2 and I've replaced the old ftplib with the newer one from Python2.7 that allows importing of FTP_TLS. Yet the following hangs up on me:

`from ftplib import FTP_TLS`

`ftp = FTP_TLS('host', 'username', 'password')`

`ftp.retrlines('LIST')` (Times out after 15-20 min)

I'm able to run these three lines successfully in a matter of seconds on my local machine, but it fails on ec2. Any idea as to why this is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly sounds like a problem related to whether or not you're in `PASSIVE` mode on your FTP connection, and whether both ends of the connection can support it.

The [ftplib documentations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html) suggests that it is on by default, which is a shame, because I was going to suggest that you turn it on.  Instead, I'll suggest that you `set_debuglevel` to where you can see the lower levels of the protocol happening and see what mode you're in.  That should give you information on how to proceed.  Either you're in passive mode and the other end can't deal with it properly, or (hopefully) you'd not, but you should be.

FTP and FTPS (but not SFTP) can be configured so that the server makes a backwards connection to the client for the actual transfers or so that the client makes a second forward connection to the server for the transfers.  The former, especially, is prone to complications whenever network address translation is involved.   Without the TLS, some firewalls can actually rewrite the FTP session traffic to make it magically work, but with TLS that's impossible due to encryption.

The fact that are presumably authenticating and then timing out when you try to transfer data (LIST requires a 2nd connection in one direction or the other) is the classic symptom, usually, of a setup that either needs passive mode, OR, there's this:

> Connect as usual to port 21 implicitly securing* the FTP control connection before authenticating.  Securing the data connection requires the user to explicitly ask for it by calling the prot_p() method.

```
ftps.prot_p()          # switch to secure data connection
ftps.retrlines('LIST') # list directory content securely
```

I don't work with FTPS often, since SFTP is so much less problematic, but if you're not doing that, the far end server might not be cooperating.

*note, I suspect this sentence is trying to say that FTP_TLS "implicitly secures the FTP control connection" in contrast with the explicit securing of the data connection.

Comment: Could it be that the server is blocking the connection from ec2? I've called prot_p() and set_pasv('true'). I also successfully returned the welcome message. As I mentioned, I was able to list the files locally -- I set_debuglevel and watched the renderings -- ec2 and local produced the same output.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having trouble could you try ruling out Amazon firewall problems. *(I'm assuming you're not using a host based firewall.)*

If your EC2 instance is **in a VPC** then in the AWS Management Console could you:

- ensure you have an internet gateway
- ensure that the subnet your EC2 instance is in has a default route (0.0.0.0/0) configured pointing at the internet gateway
- in the Security Group for both inbound and outbound allow All Traffic from all sources (0.0.0.0/0)
- in the Network ACLs for both inbound and outbound allow All Traffic from all sources (0.0.0.0/0)

If your EC2 instance is **NOT in a VPC** then in the AWS Management Console could you:

- in the Security Group for inbound allow All Traffic from all sources (0.0.0.0/0)

**Only do this in a test environment! *(obviously)***

This will open your EC2 instance up to all traffic from the internet. Hopefully you'll find that your FTPS is now working. Then you can gradually reapply the security rules until you find out the cause of the problem. If it's still not working then the AWS firewall is not the cause of the problem (or you have more than one problem).